# Uplaod big file not all in memory

Tags: go, upload, client, mime

I use to upload files to a site with this bash command:

```
cmd2=$(curl -F "$FileField=@$FileName" -F "signature=$Sig" -F "ajax=$Ajax"  -F "params=$Params" "$Url")
```

Now I've converted to golang and I use this function:

```
// Open the file.
file, err := os.Open(k.Path)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Open File", err)
    return
}

// Schedule the file to be closed once
// the function returns.
defer file.Close()

// Create a synchronous in-memory pipe. This pipe will
// allow us to use a Writer as a Reader.
pipeReader, pipeWriter := io.Pipe()

var mpWriter *multipart.Writer

body2 := &bytes.Buffer{}

// Create a goroutine to perform the write since
// the Reader will block until the Writer is closed.
go func() {

    // Create a Reader that writes to the hash what it reads
    // from the file.
    fileReader := io.TeeReader(file, body2)

    // Create the multipart writer to put everything together.
    mpWriter = multipart.NewWriter(pipeWriter)
    fileWriter, err := mpWriter.CreateFormFile(responseObject.FileField, filepath.Base(k.Path))

    // Write the contents of the file to the multipart form.
    _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, fileReader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Write File", err)
        return
    }

    // Add the keys we generated.
    mpWriter.WriteField("ajax", strconv.FormatBool(responseObject.FormData.Ajax))
    mpWriter.WriteField("params", responseObject.FormData.Params)
    mpWriter.WriteField("signature", responseObject.FormData.Signature)

    // Close the Writer which will cause the Reader to unblock.
    defer mpWriter.Close()
    defer pipeWriter.Close()
}()

// Wait until the Writer is closed, then write the
// Pipe to Stdout.
io.Copy(body2, pipeReader)

client := &http.Client{}

// Send post request
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", responseObject.FormAction, body2)

req.Header.Set("Content-Type", mpWriter.FormDataContentType())

// Submit the request
res, err := client.Do(req)
...
```

for small files I don't have problems, but when I try to upload big files, it loads the file all in memory and program crash.

I try to find a solution but without success, what can I modify?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a memory image of the stream, and then streaming that memory image to the server. Instead, you should use the pipe directly so only small chunks of the large file are in memory at any given time:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", responseObject.FormAction, pipeReader)
```

Do not use the `body2` buffer.

Comment: I tried, but in this way I think that I have problems with the WriteField because I get an error about the wrong signature, like it doesn't pass to the request

Comment: WriteField calls are not affected by this change. What exactly is the error?

Comment: I get the response from the server: bad request, wrong signature.

Comment: Did you also change the TeeReader to write to the pipeWriter?

Comment: Yes I changed it also

Comment: How do you calculate the hash?

Comment: I get the hash from a previus request, where I get the hash and the server available for the upload

Comment: So you don't actually calculate a hash as you read the file. In that case, you don't need the TeeReader at all. In fact with the change, you write the file twice. You should remove the TeeReader and use the file directly.

Comment: Ok, I've deleted it and change to  _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, file), but the error still there.

Comment: In that case: is the hash really correct? Did the file make it to the server correctly?

Comment: If I run the code I wrote in the question, the file is uploaded with no erros. Ive deleted the "body2" variable and I have that error, só I guess the hash is correct

Comment: You are probably missing the content type, because the content type is not available when you set the header. Try moving the construction of the multipart reader before the goroutine so you can set the header correctly.

Comment: You mean move  mpWriter.WriteField("ajax", strconv.FormatBool(responseObject.FormData.Ajax))
mpWriter.WriteField("params", responseObject.FormData.Params)
mpWriter.WriteField("signature", responseObject.FormData.Signature) before the goroutine? Don't I get an error?

Comment: No. Move ` mpWriter = multipart.NewWriter(pipeWriter)` before the goroutine.

Comment: Nothin: {\"name\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"Wrong signature. IP 1.2.3.4\",\"code\":0,\"status\":400} I get same error

Comment: I suggest instead of sending it to the server, write the output to a file so you can figure out what part of the request is wrong.

Comment: As you can see there aren't any datas ` &{POST https://www.example.com/upload HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=f29cb5342cef3c98ca27btrytrru77458d386d51d62c932a1b70168f87144815]] 0xc00014a7c8 <nil> 0 [] false www.example.com map[] map[] <nil> map[]   <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc00002a0f0}`

Comment: You are printing the request, not the data you sent. The data is streamed to the server. You can write the data coming from pipeReader to a file and see what data is being submitted to the server.

Comment: So I write io.Copy(os.Stdout, pipeReader) and I get that result: ` --9ad68a5fc775133be
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="VGGG3.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream ...... (all the content of the file) -9ad68a5fc775133be
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ajax"

true
--9ad68a5fc775133becce34db2844f3836c1b38a3a70d8c632e3d91cf6fa4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params"

{"node_name":"node-25",,"expire":1588244843}
--9ad68a5fc775133becce34db2844f3836c1b38a3a70d8c632e3d91cf6fa4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

ed49ea26c88
`

Comment: That looks like a valid request to me. Maybe you could do the same with your old code and compare?

Comment: Yes is the right one, but I don't understand why I still have the error